# What does "center" in "rent-a-center" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

The name of this American store is [RAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-A-Center) which stands for Rent-A-Center

[image]

I know the concept of RAC is rent-to-buy. But what kind of "center" is meant?

Comment: Each question needs to be in its own separate post.

Comment: There are lots of words that can describe a  business establishment. "Center" is attractive there because of assonance with "rent".

Comment: Yes, it is worth posting two separate questions for this. What if one person answers one question, and someone else answers the other? Or someone answers both, but one is unsatisfactory? How would we upvote those answers? How would you accept one?

Comment: @gotube I will open two new questions. But I cannot delete this one because there already is an answer.

Comment: `I will open two new questions. But I cannot delete this one because there already is an answer.` you should explain why Juhasz's answer is not helpful because this question stood a good chance of being reopened, not do much now since I learnt you replicated this Q a second time....sigh....

Answer (score 1):

This is the name of a business, not the description of a business, so you're not meant to take the words literally.  If you did, you'd assume that Rent-A-Center were a business that rented centers, that is, somewhere you could go to rent a center.

That said, the word *center* does have some meaning here.  It's approximately this:

> **center** noun
>
> 2. e : a facility providing a place for a particular activity or service
>    a day-care *center*
>    a shopping *center*
>    a medical *center*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/center)

There are a lot of businesses with the word *center* in their names.  For example:

- Micro Center - an American computer retail store, i.e. a place that sells *micro* chips
- Carpet Center - there are a ton of small businesses with some variation of this name and they all sell carpets
- The Party Center - "Your One Stop Party Shop"