# What does the company name "rent-a-center" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I know the concept of RAC is rent-to-buy. But what kind of "center" is meant here?

Please understand my [last question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343157/) was closed and I was advised to open two new questions.

Comment: RAC is rent-to-buy?? That is wrong: There is Rent-a -Center, a company that has a location where you rent furniture. Then, there is rent-to-own (like cars or real estate).

Comment: @Lambie Yes, [RAC is rent-to-own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-A-Center) and that's an alias for [rent-to-buy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-to-own). At least that is what Wikipedia says.

Comment: Like I said, Rent-A-Center is a company that rents stuff. It is not an alias. That company may have a rent-to-own policy, too.

Comment: @Lambie RAC is rent-to-own. You can read that in the [first sentence on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-A-Center). And rent-to-own is an alias for rent-to-buy. That's in the first sentence of the [second Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-to-own).

Comment: No, it says that that company called Rent-A-Center **accounts for** 35% of the rent-to-own **market**. It is NOT an alias at all.

Comment: The second article explains: **Rent-to-own, also known as rental purchase or rent-to-buy**, is a type of legally documented transaction under which tangible property, such as furniture, consumer electronics, motor vehicles, home appliances, engagement rings, and real property, is leased in exchange for a weekly or monthly payment, with the option to purchase at some point during the agreement. AKA does not mean alias.

Comment: @Lambie That's the second sentence. The first sentence says "Rent-A-Center ... is an American ... ***rent-to-own*** company."...

Comment: It seems like a play on words: "shopping center" – "renter center" – "rent-a-center". I presume "rent-a-center" is the name of the place where you arrange RAC.

Comment: The point is that there is **no alias**; also known as, aka is not an alias.

Comment: Rent-A-Center

Rent-A-Center
https://www.rentacenter.com
Rent name brand furniture, electronics, appliances, computers & smartphones from Rent-A-Center. **Rent name brand furniture**. Sure, that can go to ownership too.

Comment: Is the word *alias* being used here as a synonym for *synonym*?

Comment: I edited your first question totally unaware that you asked the same question a second time, I thought you would ask a new one about the company's slogan not the meaning of "center". Oh well ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

The name is modeled on such phrases as “rent a car.” They dropped the *car* and left open the slot for the complement of the verb *rent* in order to create a sort of fill-in-the-blank effect: “rent all kinds of things.” Then they tacked on *Center* to parallel such terms as “shopping center” in order to convey the sense that theirs is the one centralized place where all customers (clients?) should come for all their rental (or rent-to-buy) needs.

The near rhyme, “renta senta,” is further justification for the name; it makes it catchy.

Answer (score 0):

There are businesses called *rent-a-_____*.  These terms are exocentric compounds: *Sherwood Rent-a-car* is not a kind of car.  But sometimes a morpheme productive of exocentric compounds is repurposed to form endocentric compounds (*permutahedron* is an annoying example) and so it appears to have happened here.

TLDR: Business names need not make literal sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the linked question, there is an answer that isolates the applicable [MW dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/center) meaning of the word.

> **center** *noun*
>
> 2. e : a facility providing a place for a particular activity or service...
>    a shopping *center*

In the picture of the logo in that question, we see the words:
*Furniture*
*Appliances*
*Electronics*
*Computers*

When choosing a name for their business, entrepreneurs  may use allusions to associate their enterprise with similar, better established, enterprises to give potential customers an idea of what activities or services are on offer.

Here, the name borrows from the very recognizable **Rent-A-Car** service brand to imply that it is a **Center** that offers similar services for the furniture, appliances, electronics, and computers that appear on their logo.

In this context, we can infer that the business, **RAC: Rent-A-Center**, is:
a facility that provides a place where customers can utilize their services to rent: Furniture, Appliances, Electronics, and Computers

From the web search description for the company, we learn that, indeed, customers can:

> Rent name brand furniture, electronics, appliances, computers &
> smartphones from Rent-A-Center.

*No link is provided because visiting their website triggers an attempt to download cookies.*